# inherit from Javascript Array or typed array

Tags: javascript, arrays, firefox, inheritance

I want to make a JavaScript class `vector` which is a zero-initialized array. I'll probably want to add math functionality later, but I don't want to sacrifice the memory or performance qualities of the native types because the program operates on a lot of data. (It's basically scientific visualization.)

To insert `Array.prototype` in the prototype chain, I tried to use

```
vector.prototype = Object.create( Array.prototype );
```

Firefox gives me an error

> TypeError: Array.prototype.toSource called on incompatible Object

Is this a bug in Firefox? It seems to work in Webkit.

So, I tried to use `Float32Array` which is closer to what I want, and zero-initialized by default anyway.

```
var vector = function( size ) { Float32Array.call( this, size ); }
vector.prototype = Object.create( Float32Array.prototype );
```

In Firefox, this runs but `new` doesn't initialize objects properly. In Webkit `new vector` throws an exception. Makes no difference if I use `vector.prototype = Float32Array.prototype` instead.

Am I fundamentally asking for too much?

Comment: @FelixKling Sounds like… and `toSource` is a Firefox-only extension, so it's certainly not mandated by the standard. My main question is whether it's being nonstandard by throwing an exception.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Is it a bug in Firefox? Or is `Object.create( Array.prototype );` illegal for some obscure reason?

Comment: This is a good article on this very subject: http://perfectionkills.com/how-ecmascript-5-still-does-not-allow-to-subclass-an-array/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is this a reasonable way to 'subclass' a javascript array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4761000/is-this-a-reasonable-way-to-subclass-a-javascript-array)

Answer (score 3):

It is nearly impossible to truly inherit from the JavaScript Array because of very special functionality that is built in to the language and how it handles arrays.  You will see a ton of answers but most of them will fail under special circumstances.
1) if you inherit it, it will lose the special length properties.
2) if you use the __ ProtoType __ variable, it is non standard and will not work on all browsers.
3) There are many ways of detecting arrays in 3rd party libraries that might fail when checked. instanceof  Array.isArray and ==['Object Array'] could all be used.

For more detailed reading, I would suggest this article [How ECMA still does not allow to subclass array](http://perfectionkills.com/how-ecmascript-5-still-does-not-allow-to-subclass-an-array/)

I have a solution of returning a real array and avoiding all of these issues.
Here is the fiddle [Inhetit from JavaScript Array](https://jsfiddle.net/jfallin/qftv1w8s/4/)
There are detection, length and functionality tests on the fiddle.

```
var ArrayGenerator = (function () {
    var args = [].slice.call(arguments);
    var Arr = new Array();
    var ovevar ArrayGenerator = (function () {
    var args = [].slice.call(arguments);
    var Arr = new Array();
    var overiddenPush = Arr.push;
    args.forEach(function (arg) {
        Arr.push(arg);
    });
    args = null;
    Arr.push = function (args) {
        overiddenPush.apply(this, arguments);
    }
    Arr.TableName = "YourTable";
    return Arr;
});
```

//You initialize your array like this

```
    var MyArray=new ArrayGenerator(1,2,3);
```

1. Returns Real Array
2. No Detection Issues
3. Allows you to override everything you want and add custom properties and methods just like an inherited array.

You simply create an array, store the original methods in internal variables and replace the public methods with you own.  To call the base, you simple call your referenced methods instead of prototype like a regular inherited object.